# Find all files in a directory and process only ones that have a specific line, skip if does not

Tags: python-3.x, search

Need help, I’m new to python, 
I wrote a script that should find all files in a directory and process only ones that have a specific line and skip the ones that do not have the line. The specific line is ‘,"  Run  Time’
it fails to process ONLY files I need, it processes all files.

All Lines to find:

1. ‘,"  Run  Time’
2. ‘,”  Start Time’
3. ‘,”  End Time’
4. ‘Test_ID e:’
5. ‘Test Program Name:’
6. ‘Product:’

Lines 1, 2 and 3 are repeating lines and I need them all,
Lines 4, 5 and 6 also repeating but I need to capture them only ones.

import os

```
runtime_l = ',"  Run  Time'
start_tm  = ',"  Start Time'
end_tm    = ',"  End  Time'
test_ID   = ' Host Name: '
program_n = 'Test Program Name:'
prod_n    = 'Product:'

given_path = 'C:\\02\\en15\\TST'
for filename in os.listdir(given_path):
    filepath = os.path.join(given_path, filename)
    if os.path.isfile(filepath):
        print("File Name:   ", filename) 
        print("File Name\\Path:", filepath) 
        with open(filepath) as mfile:        
            for line in mfile:
                if runtime_l in line:
                    # do something with the line
                    print(line)

                if start_tm in line:
                    # do something with the line
                    print(line)  

                if end_tm in line:
                    # do something with the line
                    print(line) 

                if test_ID in line:
                    # do something with the line
                    print (line)

                if program_n in line:
                    # do something with the line
                    print (line)

                if prod_n in line:
                    # do something with the line
                    print (line)
                else:
```

## continue

Hers is snippet on how I would test a file if it has a "Run Time" line.
Not sure if it is "pythony" looking script but it does what I need. It finds files with the line I want and proccesses them.

```
import os

runtime_l = ',"  Run  Time'
start_tm  = ',"  Start Time'
end_tm    = ',"  End  Time'

given_path = 'C:\\02\\en15\\TST'
for filename in os.listdir(given_path):
    filepath = os.path.join(given_path, filename)
    if os.path.isfile(filepath):
        #print("File Name:   ", filename) 
        #print("File Name\\Path:", filepath) 
        with open(filepath) as mfile:        
            for line in mfile:
                if runtime_l in line:
                    #runtime_file = open(filepath, 'r')
                    with open(filepath) as runtime_file:
                        for rn_l in runtime_file:
                            if runtime_l in rn_l: 
                                print (rn_l)
                            elif start_tm  in rn_l:
                                print (rn_l)
                            elif end_tm  in rn_l:
                                print (rn_l)
```

Comment: Todd, thank you for the answers but it is not what I'm asking for or maybe I do not understand your answer.  first, I need to process only files that have the "Run Time" line.  Second I need to capture only the first match for lines 4,5 and 6 see the original request. I appreciate your help!

Comment: Todd! I really appreciate your help but I'm new to Python and your tips might be great but I cannot use them- I do not understand them.

Comment: How I can test files in a directory to find if a file has a line (Run time) and if it has I need to process it and disregard the ones that do not have the line.  I need to process all the files with (Run Time) string. Need to find 6 specific lines ( see original post). For  ines 4,5,6 I'd like to print only the first match (of the line). If the script finds 10 or 15 lines that matching lines 4,5,6 I need to print only 1 match of each line.

Comment: You're going to have to open each file and read in some text to determine if the rest of the file should be processed. There's no way around that. The only question is where in the file you expect to find that text - you can possibly just read in the first n lines of a file, or the last n lines (using `seek()`) to check for it, then process the whole file if found.

Answer (score 0):

Using a generator with `any()` to determine if a certain string is in a file:

```
if any(tgt_str in line for line in my_file):

    print("string found")

else:
    print("not found")
```

`any()` hosts a generator and will stop at the first line that has the target string and return `True`. If the string isn't in the file, it will be scanned to the end and `any()` will return `False`. *See below for a very brief intro to generators and list comprehensions.*

```
any(line for line in my_file if tgt_str in line)
```

Also works. `next()` can also be used, but it will raise a `StopIteration` if the string isn't found in the file.

The below preserves the majority of your code with some additions.

```
runtime_l = ',"  Run  Time'
start_tm  = ',"  Start Time'
end_tm    = ',"  End  Time'
test_ID   = ' Host Name: '
program_n = 'Test Program Name:'
prod_n    = 'Product:'

class OneTime:
    def __init__(self):
        self.test_ID    = 0
        self.program_n  = 0
        self.prod_n     = 0

    def all_done(self):
        return self.test_ID & self.program_n & self.prod_n


given_path = './test_logs'

for filename in os.listdir(given_path):
    filepath = os.path.join(given_path, filename)

    if not os.path.isfile(filepath):
        continue

    with open(filepath, 'r') as mfile:

        if not any(runtime_l in ln for ln in mfile):
            continue # Onto the next file...

        # If we get this far, we know the runtime_l string is in
        # the file. Proceed...

        mfile.seek(0) # Back to start of file.

        one_time      = OneTime()
        one_time_done = 0

        print("File Name:      ", filename) 
        print("File Name\\Path:", filepath) 

        for line in mfile:

            line = line.rstrip()

            if runtime_l in line:
                # do something with the line
                print(line)

            elif start_tm in line:
                # do something with the line
                print(line)  

            elif end_tm in line:
                # do something with the line
                print(line) 

            elif not one_time_done:

                if not one_time.test_ID and test_ID in line:
                    # do something with the line
                    one_time.test_ID = 1
                    print(line)

                elif not one_time.program_n and program_n in line:
                    # do something with the line
                    one_time.program_n = 1
                    print(line)

                elif not one_time.prod_n and prod_n in line:
                    # do something with the line
                    one_time.prod_n = 1
                    print(line)

                one_time_done = one_time.all_done()
```

The `OneTime` class's role is just to host variables indicating whether one of the one-time printed lines have already been printed. You could use a dict, or just plain variables to keep track of that.

The statement inside the `any(...)` function creates a *generator* which produces items when iterated over. It's like a list that you get values from one-by-one, except it's lazy. The items aren't stored inside it, but read in as-needed when `any()` asks for each line until it hits one that evaluates to `True`.

I know it seems like advanced stuff when you're new to Python and trying to learn. I'll give a brief explanation and provide a link below if you want to learn more.

In a nutshell, I'm not sure if you've become familiar with "list comprehensions" yet, but I'm sure you've seen them. They look like for loops inside square braces and produce list items:

```
>>> li = [char for char in "abcdefghijklmnop"]
>>> li
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p']
```

This ^ would create a list of characters, since when you iterate over a string, it produces one character at a time.

A generator looks like a list comprehension inside parenthesis (instead of square braces) and has the same effect, but the characters aren't produced until asked for:

```
>>> gen  = (char for char in "abcdefghijklmnop")
>>> gen
<generator object <genexpr> at 0x7f9a447aec10>
>>> next(gen)
'a'
```

So, back to `any()`. It will pull items from the generator until it sees something that evaluates to `True` and then it'll stop. It's only looking for *any* value that's True in a sequence of items.

```
>>> any([False, False, False, True])
True
>>>
>>> any("foo" in line for line in ["bar", "baz", "foo", "qux"])
True
```

When iteration hits `"foo"`, the expression `"foo" in line` is `True`. Iteration stops there. The whole statement in the parameter list of `any()` is a generator - sometimes they don't need their own parenthesis when used as a parameter.

In much the same way as the last example, the file generator will read in one line at a time until `any()` is satisfied - and it'll go no further. So in that way it's somewhat efficient.

Here's a basic tutorial if you're interested: https://www.csestack.org/python-fibonacci-generator/.

Comment: Thanks, Todd! Is there a way in Python when I could just reload a file after the first match found? and start looking for another viable to match? I'm asking this because the snippets you wrote do not do what I want and I cannot modify them because I do not understand them. I'm new to this.

Comment: @VladePast, I removed my complicated examples and used your code. So the code in the examples now is mostly yours ;-).  Take a new look at it, and don't  pay much attention to `check_file()`.. but see if the second snippet would be workable for you.

Comment: @VladePast.. hold on.. i'll remove all the extra and put just the minimal up.

Comment: Todd! If you would live in Portland Oregon I will buy you a drink after the quarantine is gone ;)

Comment: Sure Vlade. I don't drink though =/

Comment: @VladePast I just updated it. The `print_line()` function needed to clear the list after it printed it. The line I added was:  `stored_lines.clear()`

Comment: You mean replace "print_line()" with "stored_lines.clear()"?

Comment: @VladePast nah.. forget that. I removed it. Try using the current version here.

Comment: Just posted a new snippet for testing files for a line in it. it somehow does not look "Pythony" to me but it does the job.

Comment: The nesting looks awkward. You already have the file open, and inside the loop processing its lines, you open it again and start an inner loop. That's not necessary. @VladePast. Instead of starting that inner loop, just `break` when you find the text you're looking for and set a variable that you found it. Then in a new loop open the file and process it.

Comment: I was sure it looks awkward.  "Then in a new loop open the file and process it."- what does it mean? Did I just do "new loop open the file "?

Comment: I kind of stumbled on to the trick using `any()` looking at your code and trying different things. If you want a "pythonic" solution, it's pretty pythonic. I don't think it's uncommon to see this though - but it's new to me ;-) it's a neat trick. @VladePast

Comment: "any" looks interesting, let's I'll try it. Thank you again for your help Todd!